# JavaScript load "header.xhtml" works offline but not online

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, iframe, xhtml

The background:
I am trying to build a website using JSF and xhtml for university, deploying Eclipse EE as my IDE. At the moment, I am trying to find a way to include a "header.xhtml" in my "index.xhtml" in a way that works both offline (Tomcat 8 as part of Eclipse) and online (an online server by the German provider "Alfahosting").

When trying to include the "header.xhtml" (located in the same directory as the index.xhtml) via Javascript, *it works fine offline*, while online it doesnt (just shows the page without the header, as visible here: http://danielmethner.com/ )
However, JavaScript itself DOES work when used on the webseite, as I found out by including a "hello world"-alert which works fine online and offline.

The index.xhtml bit with Javascript is here:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!--=============== Doctype Declaration =================-->

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
        xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<!--==================== Header =========================-->
<h:head>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="body.css"/>  
    <title>Web Development Project</title>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $("#header").load("header.xhtml"); 
            $("#footer").load("footer.xhtml"); 
        }); 
    </script>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <style>
        #index {
            font-weight: bolder;
        }
    </style>
</h:head>
```

The alternative I've found on the internet was iframe (which I used in the footer of the page in the link). However, iframe *does not work offline* but only online. When used offline, it moves every time I click on it. When using online instead, it doesnt move anymore but it opens any links in the same window (which seems to be inherent of iframe?).

So basically, I was wondering if anyone knows why this piece of javascript would work offline on my localhost but not online?

Or if I should maybe concentrate fully on iframe instead or even use a different approach which I don´t know yet?

ps. Please excuse any formal & language mistakes in this post since this is my first question asked on stackoverflow (and I'm a "foreigner"). Also I am aware that there have been quite a number of similar questions, which I have done research on for two days straight now so here I am asking one of these questions again.

Either way, many thanks Your help!

EDIT: I just realised that my question looks a bit like an ad-post. If I should remove the external links/ the name of my online provider I shall be happy to do so.

Comment: The link to the header that is not shown in the example is http://danielmethner.com/header.xhtml

Comment: The best practice is to use <h:outputScript library="js" name="jquery.js" /> instead of <script> tag. Try moving your code to a separate JavaScript file and include using <h:outputScript>.

Comment: Your technical problem is answered in abovelinked duplicate. Your http://xyproblem.info is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4792862

Comment: So the tag in the index.xhtml would be 
<h:outputScript library="js" name="resources/js/jquery.js" />
and the JavaScript code in the separate file "jquery.js" in the directory "resources/js/" would be

$(function(){
 $("#header").load("header.xhtml"); 
 $("#footer").load("footer.xhtml"); 
}); 
?